# Removing the product counter in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, inventory, product-quantity

I do not need the product counter, under a Product and before the `ADD TO CARD` button, for my variable products. One product can be like 10000 pieces.

Do not need to ADD, for example, 2 times 10000 pieces.

[image]

How I can remove the product counter in WooCommerce?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In woocommerce product page settings for your product go in Inventory options tab, then enable "Sold individually". That's all.